# Can I change one of two Request Bodies in one http-request logically?

Tags: java, spring, request

I develop some Spring program, and use jdbcTemplate for querying with the Postgres database.
I got this case:
Need to search object1 by name in database, if object1 exist, then create object2, else create object1 and create object2.
The problem is, my function got two type of objects and when I use it in Controller I can't use two @Request Bodies in the same time in one request.
Got this problem any decision?
Please help)

Here is the code:

```
public void addNewVersionOfService(Version version, Service service, String service_name) {
        String sql = "SELECT id FROM tb_services WHERE name = ?";
           int serviceId = jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(sql, Integer.class, service_name);

            if(serviceId !=0){
                sql = "INSERT INTO tb_versions (id, service_id, version, created_date) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)";
                    jdbcTemplate.update(sql, version.getId(), serviceId, version.getVersion(), version.getCreated_date());
                        sql = "SELECT id FROM tb_versions WHERE created_date=?";
                            int versionId = jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(sql, Integer.class, version.getCreated_date());
            } else {
                serviceDAO.addNewService(service);

                  sql = "INSERT INTO tb_versions (id, service_id, version, created_date) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)";
                jdbcTemplate.update(sql, version.getId(), serviceId, version.getVersion(), version.getCreated_date());
                    sql = "SELECT id FROM tb_versions WHERE created_date=?";
                        int versionId = jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(sql, Integer.class, version.getCreated_date());
            }
    }
```

And here is the Controller.class:

```
@PostMapping("versions/service")
public ResponseEntity<Version> addNewVersionOfService(@RequestBody Version version, @RequestBody Service service, @RequestParam("name") String serviceName){
    versionService.addNewVersionOfService(version, service, serviceName);
}
```

Comment: Why don't you just create/use a class that holds Version and Service?

Comment: Mihe, hi! Thats a good idea, I get used to work with entities in database and got that case for the first time. But if I need to create only one object (Version), because Service already exist, that I need to use all parameters in this class in request body? Or I can write logic in a class that will choose between objects. And then pass the class object to metod.

Comment: No, usually an object of that class is created and the values which are present in the request body will be set. The other values remain untouched.

Answer (score 0):

This is a style question with several options.  Your issue is with the structure of your controller's mapping.

### Option 1

Create a single class to hold both items.

```java
@PostMapping(value = "versions/service")
public ResponseEntity<Version> addNewVersionOfService(@RequestBody serviceVersion, @RequestParam("name") String serviceName){
    Version version = serviceVersion.getVersion();
    Service service = serviceVersion.getService();
    versionService.addNewVersionOfService(version, service, serviceName);
}
```

### Option 2

add one of them to the mapping as a path parameter.  Depending on the size of the object, version or service may be able to be set in the path.

```java
@PostMapping("{version}/service")
public ResponseEntity<Version> addNewVersionOfService(@PathVariable("version") Version version, @RequestBody Service service, @RequestParam("name") String serviceName){
    versionService.addNewVersionOfService(version, service, serviceName);
}
```

### Option 3:

Break your endpoint into two endpoints and leave the logic up to your consumer.  I don't necessarily recommend this if version and system are tightly coupled, but if it can be split out it may be useful for your REST consumer to be able to set their service and version separately.

```java
// create object 1 here
@PostMapping("versions")
public ResponseEntity<Version> addNewVersionOfService(@RequestBody Version version, @RequestBody Service service, @RequestParam("name") String serviceName){
    versionService.addNewVersionOfService(version, service, serviceName);
}

// create object 2 here.  throw error if object 1 doesn't exist
@PostMapping("versions/service")
public ResponseEntity<Version> addNewVersionOfService(@RequestBody Version version, @RequestBody Service service, @RequestParam("name") String serviceName){
    versionService.addNewVersionOfService(version, service, serviceName);
}
```